# How to pass unique data to bootstrap modal in while loop

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli

I am trying to create a delete-button for each printed row in a php while loop that opens a modal window. The delete query will be executed from the modal.

How can I pass the corresponding row's id, title etc to the modal?
The way it is now, I only get the data from the first table row no matter what delete-button I press.

There are many solutions out there, but I can't make them work.
Hoping someone can help me understand this...

Comment: My best guess would be to write some code, might want to show us what you have so far and what you are stuck with?

Comment: Onclick in each row call a function _openModalDelete(idRow). Inside this func you can open the default modal, and change any data into the modal to set the idRow. In the modal's button click you must check this data to get the idRow clicked

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server side, so it really needs done in Javascript.

I created a Javascript lib if you are interested called bs-delete-confirm. you add a class to your delete button, and when you click it, it stops an href from leaving the page and brings up a Bootstrap modal asking if you are sure you wish to perform the action. Clicking ok follows the link, clicking cancel doesn't. Simple!.

Check it out here https://github.com/delboy1978uk/bs-delete-confirm

```
<a href="/delete-url" class="delete-class">X</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.delete_class').deleteConfirm();
});
```

and that's it! you now have a delete confirm modal :-)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to create a hidden modal in the bottom of my html and clone it into a new variable, then change the data for that new modal, append it and fire it up.

That way when you delete it or need to create a second one, you always have access to your template/blueprint.
It also allows you to keep a separate reference to every modal for later use.

eg `$modal1.find('.inputEmail')` and `$modal2.find('.inputEmail')`

You can even make that dynamic afterwards if you have many inputs